# Graphhopper: ClassCastException when calculating path with CH Astar/Dikstra Bi

Tags: graphhopper

Using only WGS84 coordinates I can [write the graph and index to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40514141/4121087). In another java project I read graph and index from disk. This also works fine with the following code.

```
FlagEncoder encoder = new CarFlagEncoder();
EncodingManager em = new EncodingManager(encoder);

GraphBuilder gb = new GraphBuilder(em).
    setLocation(testDir).
    setStore(true).
    setCHGraph(new FastestWeighting(encoder));

// Load and use the graph
GraphHopperStorage graph = gb.load();

// Load index
LocationIndex index = new LocationIndexTree(graph.getBaseGraph(), graph.getDirectory());
if (!index.loadExisting())
    throw new IllegalStateException("location index cannot be loaded!");

AlgorithmOptions algoOpts = AlgorithmOptions.start().algorithm(Parameters.Algorithms.ASTAR_BI).
traversalMode(TraversalMode.NODE_BASED).
weighting(new FastestWeighting(encoder)).
build();

PrepareContractionHierarchies pch = new PrepareContractionHierarchies(graph.getDirectory(), graph, graph.getGraph(CHGraphImpl.class), new FastestWeighting(encoder), TraversalMode.NODE_BASED);
pch.doWork();

QueryResult fromQR = index.findClosest(fromCoordinate.x, fromCoordinate.y, EdgeFilter.ALL_EDGES);
QueryResult toQR = index.findClosest(toCoordinate.x, toCoordinate.y, EdgeFilter.ALL_EDGES);
QueryGraph queryGraph = new QueryGraph(graph);
queryGraph.lookup(fromQR, toQR);

RoutingAlgorithm algorithm = pch.createAlgo(queryGraph, algoOpts);

Path path = algorithm.calcPath(fromQR.getClosestNode(), toQR.getClosestNode());
```

However, first I wonder why the preparation of the contraction hierarchies needs so much time. I would have expected that the preparation had been done already. Is this done again? What's the purpose of the file named "shortcuts_fastest_car"?

Second, I receive a confusing `ClassCastException` once `algorithm.calcPath` is called.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.graphhopper.storage.BaseGraph$EdgeIterable cannot be cast to com.graphhopper.util.CHEdgeIteratorState
at com.graphhopper.routing.util.LevelEdgeFilter.accept(LevelEdgeFilter.java:48)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AbstractRoutingAlgorithm.accept(AbstractRoutingAlgorithm.java:79)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AStarBidirection.fillEdges(AStarBidirection.java:217)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AStarBidirection.fillEdgesFrom(AStarBidirection.java:194)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AbstractBidirAlgo.runAlgo(AbstractBidirAlgo.java:68)
at com.graphhopper.routing.AbstractBidirAlgo.calcPath(AbstractBidirAlgo.java:61)
```

What's going wrong? Is there some config flag missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to pass the CH graph

`graph.getGraph(CHGraphImpl.class)`

instead of just `graph` to the QueryGraph constructor.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That did the trick. Would be great if the [documentation](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/low-level-api.md) could reflect the latest changes in code.

Comment: Done. Is it true that the PrepareContractionHierarchies does not require the doWork() when the already prepared files are read back from disk?

Comment: Yes (probably we should switch for discussion to our forum)